# Order of $ \sum_{i=1}^n i^{2-\epsilon} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

We know that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
So this summation is $o(n^{3+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ and consider the following sum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2-\epsilon}
$$
My question is that can we find some $\delta>0$ such that this sum is $o(n^{3-\delta})$?

Comment: You can use the relation between a sum an an integral: $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2-\epsilon} \sim \int_1^n x^{2-\epsilon}dx$ to estimate your sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let $0<\epsilon<2$. One may prove that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2-\epsilon} \sim \int_1^nx^{2-\epsilon}dx=\frac{n^{3-\epsilon}}{3-\epsilon}.
$$ Then to obtain
$$
n^{3-\epsilon}=o(n^{3-\delta})
$$ it is sufficient to take $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}2$.